# Как писать оптимизированные SQL запросы?

Tags: оптимизация, производительность, sql

Здравствуйте коллеги =). Вот читал я статьи про запросы sql от специалистов (еще года два назад), но случайным образом увидел не стыковки со статьей. Это касается оптимизация запроса.

Использование "*" в запросе не рекомендуется, что снижает производительность выполнение запроса сервером.
сделал запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM user ... // Выполняется около 0,004 секунд( Проверял тест 10 раз)

SELECT `x`, `x1`, `x2`, `xn` FROM user // Выполняется 0,0065 ( В среднем). Примерно полей 14.
```

И маленький вопрос еще. У меня есть одна таблица user. Эта таблица используется на несколько сайтов, какие находятся на одном сервере. У каждого сайта, есть свои данные какие хранятся в таблице user. Но всего лишь 30% данных, что хранятся в таблице user совпадают со всеми проектами. А остальные 70% от каждого проекта. Суть вопроса: стоит ли разбивать таблицу юзер, как основную + специальную для каждого проекта используя при запросе LEFT JOIN. Прокомментируйте как будет лучше в виде производительности?

Comment: @Node_pro - это не оптимизация, это экономия на спичках, более того, ценой читабельности и понимания происходящего. Перечисление колонок делает ваш запрос более наглядным, а в то, что это самое перечисление может стать узким местом я не верю, если ошибаюсь - поправьте.

Comment: Это почему звездочка понятнее для читающего запрос, чем явное указание колонок? 
Оптимизация в этом случае совсем не иллюзорная. Из личного опыта - никогда не гнушаюсь заменять звездочку на укзание произвольного поля в подзапросах. Это позволит компилятору не отвлекаться на составление списка колонок

Comment: имеет смысл, только в том случае если у вас намечается рост нагрузки на СУБД. есть утилиты которые позволяют сделать нагрузочное тестирование для веб сайтов, - они то и помогут вам найти проблемные места (напр jmeter)

Comment: @renegator - ога, тогда любой человек, который прийдет на проект будет вынужден лезть в БД и долго и печально там копаться, да и чего греха таить то? Вы сами спустя определенное время это позабудете.

Comment: ну 20 лет работы чему то учат. например - писать комментарии

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема звёздочки - рост трафика, ибо далеко не всегда используются все поля, а вы их передали.

Что-бы понять источник разницы скорости двух запросов - надо смотреть их планы выполнения... Разное бывает... Из личного опыта на http://sql-ex.ru, добавив в одном из подзапросов что-то типа

```
union all select 0
```

скорость возросла на 10-20%...

Answer (score 5):

Использование звездочки в запросе не рекомендуется не по причине повышения производительности, а по той причине, что, используя ее в запросе, вы рискуете впоследствии нарваться на падение некоторых своих запросов/процедур при изменении таблицы.

Пример запроса:

```
Insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3)
select * from table2
```

Он перестанет выполняться, если в table2 добавится еще одна колонка.

По второму: Не вижу смысла в использовании left join. Если уж объединять таблицы, несущие одинаковый смысл, то делать это надо через union all. А нужно ли это - зависит от бизнес-логики.

Comment: А подскажите, а при обычном запросе, стоит ли писать название полей или проще "*". Насчет второго запроса к примеру: `SELECT u.*, a.* FROM users as u LEFT JOIN таблица используется только в этом проекте as a ON u.id=a.id`

Comment: Если запрос написан для "посмотреть, что в таблице", и будет после удален, то можно и так. Во всех остальных случаях хороший тон - перечисление колонок.

Comment: уточню. У меня на каждой странички 3 глобальных запроса (юзер, статистика, новости). Эти данные запихиваю в массив и использую визде, то тут лучше * использовать?

Comment: А я вот не понял, почему запрос в вашем примере перестанет выполнятся ? Ну ладно, с инсертом еще понятно, хотя эта проблема решается если в запросе четко указать колонки в которые добавлять информацию, но со 2 примером не понятно, * же подразумевает собой выборку всех колонок...

Comment: Всё это враки! :) Звездочка это не панацея, просто нужно знать что делаешь.

Comment: @tranceman кроме mysql есть еще и другие субд, которые более трогательно относятся к количеству и качеству колонок. в частности, если идет аггрегирование, то перечисление всех полей, не входящих в аггрегацию, в секции group by обязательно. после добавления колонки в таблицу при использовании * в таких запросах рискуете провести немало веселых минут/часов в исправлении таких случаев. что касается mysql, то там можно получить вообще не очевидные результаты, опуская группировку, в случае со звездочкой в том числе...

Answer (score 5):

Предварительная оптимизация - ЗЛО!

Вы пишите как вы считаете нужным, а уже в следствии тестирования приложения смотрите что и сколько выполняется. Ведите лог обращений к базе, какой запрос, сколько выполняется, сколько записей вернуло.

На "тяжелых" запросах делайте EXPLAIN и добавляйте нужные индексы либо по другому написать запрос. Всё приходит с опытом, сразу научится писать "оптимизированные" запросы не получится.

Comment: Я как бы не первый день в Веб-сфере, я всегда перечислял как по "книжке", а вчера посмотрел и огорчился =)

Comment: @Node_pro И, тем не менее, всё равно следует перечислять, как "по книжке". Это существенно продлит ваши дни в Веб-сфере. Или, по крайней мере, сделает их более счастливыми. А производительность можно повысить, используя prepare для повторяющихся запросов.

Comment: prepare только для mysqli? Не могли бы вы меня послать желательно на русский мануал

Comment: @Node_pro Не знаю, что такое mysqli. Видимо, какая-то библиотека для доступа к mysql-базе. Но операция prepare есть везде и для любой sql-базы. А те языки и/или библиотеки, в которых её почему-то вдруг нет, просто не надо использовать для хоть сколько-нибудь серьёзной работы с sql-запросами.

Comment: дайте ссылку на мануал, пожалуйста на русском)

Answer (score 1):

Оценка скорости в данном примере необъективна. Так как оптимизатор добавил в кэш ваш запрос при первом выполнении, таким образом при последующих выполнениях для данного запроса не выполняются такие трудоемкие операции как оптимизация запроса, проверка привилегий и прочие операции, характерные для запросов. выполняющихся впервые. Таким образом, чтобы оценивать скорость выполнения запросов нужно чистить кэш, вот тогда можно будет судить о том какой запрос выполняется быстрее.

Comment: Не чистил кэшь, но проверял по очереди, и результат написал вверху. разница примерно в 0,002 секунды.